# How can I scroll tabs without closing drawer?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use Material UI in my project. I have scrollable tabs inside the swipeable drawer. In the mobile version when I scroll tabs right side (like the image below) my drawer has been closed [drawer opens from the right side and closes from the left side]. But I want to scroll tabs without closing the drawer. Only scrolling tabs do not close the drawer. But swiping another element drawer will be closed. Can anyone help me by giving the solution? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: upload ur code plz

Comment: Look for an adequate `prop` in this MaterialUI drawer API, there must be something to control it.